# Find point inside smallest rectangle. O(n) but optimize further

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Interview question:

Given billions of rectangles, find rectangle with minimum area overlapping a given point P(x,y)

There is a simple way to achieve the answer in O(n) time by processing each rectangle sequentially, but optimize it further provided large number of Rectangle array.

My best approach would be to check each rectangle, see if the point is inside, then calculate area and compare with current smallest area. This can be done in a single pass. I cannot conceive of any other method that doesn't require checking all rectangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same rectangle set with many point queries, then [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) data structure allows to know what rectangles contain given point without checking all rectangles

Answer (score 0):

You do need to process all rectangles at least once, of course. But use that first pass wisely and you can get multiple faster lookups later on.

I would insert the rectangles into a [K-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or a [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not telling the full question. Because the way how it stands now, your solution is optimal.

No matter what you have to go through each rectangle at least one to check whether it actually covers the point and to calculate its area. There is no point to preprocess them in any way because you need to answer **only one question**.

Preprocessing only makes sense if you will need to answer many similar questions in the future.

Comment: I totally agree. Yet I think the interviewer will expect one to think of a solution that works for many queries. I think they hope one can see the trade of an expensive preprocessing pass that will make all subsequent queries LogN or less than O(n). So I think the best answer is to say "for one search only, O(n) is the best we can do. For multiple queries, it pays to use a k-tree or some other data structure"